# Update one column in table1 from value in table2

Tags: oracle11g

I am trying to update one column in table1 from a column in table2. Here
    is what i am doing but i am getting an ORA error.
    `ORA-01427: single-row subquery returns more than one row`.

```
update table1 a
 set a.art_num = (
    select b.art_num from table2 b
     where a.comp_id = b.comp_id );
```

Thanks so much in advance!

Comment: The error is due to the fact that table2 contains more than one row that meets the join condition: `a.comp_id = b.comp_id`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This happens because your subquery returns more than one result.
You should check this one:

```
select b.art_num 
from table2 b
where a.comp_id = b.comp_id
```

You could try to select [DISTINCT](https://docs.oracle.com/cd/B28359_01/server.111/b28286/statements_10002.htm) (search for distinct in the link for documentation) on the subquery:

```
update table1 a
 set a.art_num = (
    select distinct(b.art_num) 
    from table2 b
    where a.comp_id = b.comp_id );
```